# Specifications for Tor security in the transmision of Data

Tags: help, encryption

I am doing a School project based on the in depth security of tor and i can't find the up-to-date security protocols the tor uses. i have found an old thread saying it uses RSA1024 for encryption but in another thread i found that tor wanted to mitigate to Ed25519-SHA-512 but i havent found more on that please could someone explain to me what protocols tor uses and what is the up-to-date encryption used?

i have found this https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/tor-spec.txt but seems to be old?

Answer (score 1):

The `tor-spec.txt` you linked to is a more-or-less up-to-date description of how Tor works.  There may be minor divergences between that document and the running code (which makes the codebase the definitive specification), but for almost any purposes you'll be wanting it for, it is sufficient.  In particular, it describes the use of Ed25519 and Curve25519 in various parts of the protocol.